# PHP not running on Apache

Tags: php, apache, debian

I wanted php5.5 on my Debian 7 server so I added the Dotdeb repository to my sources.list since they have php5.5 in their repository

I first removed the defualt php5.4 which come with Debian 7 and after that I installed php5.5 by running

```
apt-get install php5
```

I know php 5.5 is installed by running

```
php -v
```

but now my php webpages do not get interpreted by php. How can I fix this issue?

I have tried re installing apache as well but it did not fix the issue.

Comment: try sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5 -> service apache2 restart

Comment: @dave I tried that. I even removed apache and re installed it.

Comment: thats strange, my next step would be to delete everything and try with apt-get install lamp-server^ and then remove mysql if you dont need it

Comment: Check if PHP5 module/service is configured to be loaded in web server.

Comment: @dvm which file do I need to check for that?

Comment: Check your http.conf file. If you see a line that starts: "#LoadModule php5_module", php is commented out. remove the # to activate it, and restart apache.

Comment: @Karptonite would this possibly be called apache2.conf on Debian?

Comment: a2enmod php5 solved the problem

Comment: please add an "answer" to the question and mark it as "accepted", so the question is no longer listed. also, you might want to ask similar questions on [sf], as it is really about server administration and not about programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else who runs into this problem. Here is how I solved issue.

Run this command

```
a2enmod php5
```